# Change in seek bar in Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm just wondering if the seekbar changed in Android 3.0 . I tried to create one but it showing up as a green line with a circle on it instead of the usual yellow rectangle. If so, is there any other option to create a similar seekbar to control volume on 3.0? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just wondering if the seekbar changed in Android 3.0 .

More accurately, it changed with the "holographic" theme that is the standard for Android 3.0 (and, presumably, beyond).

> I tried to create one but it showing up as a green line with a circle on it instead of the usual yellow rectangle.

Correct. That is what your users will expect to see.

> If so, is there any other option to create a similar seekbar to control volume on 3.0?

I would recommend that you leave it alone. The objective should be to give the user what they are familiar with. If most other applications with seek bars -- and the OS itself -- are using the new seek bar style, ideally you will too.

Note that the new style only takes effect if you are adopting the holographic theme (e.g., `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`), which means you are buying into the entire new Honeycomb look and feel (action bar, change to the way a `Spinner` looks, etc.).

You are welcome to use your own style and substitute in your own graphics, using the [styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html) portions of `ProgressBar` and `SeekBar` (`SeekBar` inherits from `ProgressBar`), or in your XML layouts (e.g., [`android:thumb`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#attr_android%3athumb)), or via Java code.